# How to import from a file in parent directory?

Tags: python, peewee

I have the following folder structure:

```
.
├── GET
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── database.py
├── main.py
├── models
│   ├── BaseModel.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── contact.py
└── routers
    ├── __init__.py
    └── contact.py
```

`database.py` looks like below:

```
from peewee import *

user = 'root'
password = 'root'
db_name = 'fastapi_contact'

conn = MySQLDatabase(
    db_name, user=user,
    password=password,
    host='localhost'
)

def get_connection():
    return conn
```

In the file `BaseModel.py` I am doing this:

```
from peewee import *
import os, sys
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
import database

connection = get_connection()
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = connection
```

But I am getting the error:

```
  File "./main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from routers import contact
  File "./routers/contact.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models.contact import Contact
  File "./models/contact.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import BaseModel
  File "./models/BaseModel.py", line 7, in <module>
    connection = get_connection()
NameError: name 'get_connection' is not defined
```

how do I get the `get_connection` in `BaseModel.py` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Either use

```
database.get_connection
```

or

```
from database import get_connection
```

Assuming that you have added the Root dir to the PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) might help. The follow might also do the trick:

```
from ... import database
```